# Create new tab with developer tools open

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a working Chrome Extension that opens a new tab and navigates to the specified URL. I'm looking to see if I can somehow have that new tab be opened with developer tools open as well. Is this possible?

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    active: true,
    url: "http://www.google.com"
}, createTabListener);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment. You can vote for this issue to support the feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958

Comment: That feature request is not what OP looks for though. The consensus there is to have a DevTools flag such that a link opened from a page with DevTools already open would also have DevTools open. This will not help here, for an extension API a new request is needed (e.g. an option for `create`, possibly with indicating which DevTools tab to open)